# Get value part from spinner not text part in android

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner and I bind it to the list of objects with each object containing text and id part.Text part is displayed to the user and user can select any item from the spinner. Now my question is that How can I get value part from the spinner.

I bind my spinner like this:

```
  Itm=new CItem( "-1", "Select Project" );
            lstItm.add(Itm);
            for(int i=0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject tmpJson=array.getJSONObject(i);
                Itm=new CItem(tmpJson.getString("ID"),tmpJson.getString("Text"));
                lstItm.add(Itm);
      }
     ArrayAdapter<CItem> adapterProj = new ArrayAdapter<CItem>(myactivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lstItm);
      drpProj.setAdapter(adapterProj);
```

I am trying to get value like this:

```
drpProj.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        CItem item=(CItem)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String value=item.toString();// get value
        Log.d("Selected Item",value);
        etcal.setText(value);
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

});
```

Also CItem class is like this:

public class CItem {

```
private String ID = "";
private String Value = "";

public CItem () {
    ID = "";
    Value = "";
}

public CItem (String _ID, String _Value) {
    ID = _ID;
     Value = _Value;
}

@ Override
public String toString () {// Why should override toString ()? Because the adapter display data if the incoming adapter object is not a string of case, directly on the use of the object. ToString ()
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Value;
}

public String getId () {
    return ID;
}

public String getValue () {
    return Value;
}
```

}

but it returns text part not value part. so my question is how to get value part of spinner.

Comment: try etcal.setText( ((CItem) drpProj.getSelectedItem()).getValue().toString())  ;

Comment: Where is your `onItemSelected(..)` and also post `CItem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
 itemSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           CItem item=(CItem)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
           String value=item.getValue().toString();// get value

         }
       @Override
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
       }
   });
```

in your `onItemSelected(....)`

Comment: got it...was doing it on wrong place before ...need to put this code after populating spinner with values...thx :)

Answer (score 1):

In your onItemSelected method, invoke the following to get the CItem object at the selected position on the spinner.

```
 onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
     CItem item = (CItem) parent.getSelectedItem();
     String desiredValue = item.getValue();
```

Comment: I simply tried    etcal.setText("hi");  in  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)  inside drpProj.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() ...........But it is still not working

Comment: you are saying etcal.setText('hi') doesnt set the value to 'hi'? ... but first are you getting the desired value from the spinner ?

Comment: this was just for testing if it is being called or not